# How to use Pseudo classes for more than one link?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

How can I use Pseudo Classes when I want to use in more than one link like:

```css
a.youtube,a.google:link{ color: pink;}
a.youtube,a.google:visited{ color: green; }
a.youtube,a.google:hover{ color: red; }
```

```html
<a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YOUTUBE</a>
<a class="google" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
```

It is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do to achieve what you want is to add the ":visited"/":hover" on both classes, not just the "google" class. Like so:

```css
a.youtube,a.google{
color: pink;
}

a.youtube:visited,a.google:visited{
  color: green;
}

a.youtube:hover,a.google:hover{
color: red;
}
```

Also, you don't need ":link"

**Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbLqpcm8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can archive this using one single class:

```css
.social-link,
.social-link:link {
  color: pink;
}

.social-link:visited {
  color: green;
}

.social-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="youtube social-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YOUTUBE</a>
<a class="google social-link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
```

Comment: This shows all of them in green even though I've not visited them but hover is working fine.